# Equivalent of /dev/full on OSX

Tags: macos, unix

I want some special file which throws an error when I write to it. `/dev/full` does that on Linux. I don't care too much about the specific error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing to `/dev/urandom` results in `write: Operation not permitted`.

Comment: @Toto Why do you think so?

Comment: @Ramhound It does? I asked for a special file which throws an error when I write to it. `/dev/urandom` is a special while which throws an error when I write to it, namely `Operation not permitted`.

Comment: @Ramhound the answer was posted by the asker.

Comment: @music2myear - Answer was so brief it read like a reply instead of an answer. Should have read the question more carefully

Comment: My first thought was the same as yours.